# Custom sorting algorithm for a large amount of data

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, solr, doctrine-orm

I have a large amount of data that I need to sort in a specific way based on a search query, but I'm not sure of the best approach to take.

The data I'm trying to sort is a list of courses, grouped by schools.  Each course is taught by one school.  Each school may belong to any number of "partnerships", which represents a relationship between a number of schools.  A user can search for any number of courses by the name of the course.

I need to sort the data as follows:

- Courses are grouped by school, with 10 schools appearing per page.
- Schools that can provide every course that the user has searched for should appear first in the list.
- After these results, schools that belong to a partnership that can accommodate all of the courses the user searched for should appear next to each other.

Here is an example:

- *A* teaches History, French and English courses.
- *B* teaches French and Mathematics.
- *C* teaches History.
- *B* and *C* are in a partnership together.
- *D* teaches History.
- The user searches for "History" and "French".
- *A* should appear first in the results, with its History and French courses, as it can provide both of the courses the user is looking for.
- *B*, followed by *C* appears next, with the relevant course it teaches listed after it, as the partnership can provide both of the user's required courses.
- *D* Appears next as it only provides 1 relevant course.

The data is stored in an Microsoft SQL Server database across a few tables.  Here is a simplified schema:

**Course:**

- int id
- varchar name
- int schoolId

**School:**

- int id
- varchar name

**Partnership:**

- int id
- varchar partnershipName

**SchoolPartnership:**

- int id
- int schoolId
- int partnershipId

There are over 100000 courses and around 300 schools.  I don't know of a way to sort the courses as specified in SQL, which I think is my biggest problem.  I only need to display 10 results per page, but as I can't do the sorting in the SQL query, I have to extract the entire result set and sort it manually in PHP before I can cut the result set down to 10 results.

I'm currently extracting the data I need in a single query with multiple joins using Doctrine 2, hydrating the results as an array.  Then the plan is to manipulate this big array of records in PHP to get it into the correct order.  Due to the size of this array, I'm worried that this sorting process is going to be very slow, so I'm looking for advice on how to make this quicker, either by:

- Handling the sorting in the SQL query.
- Suggesting how an algorithm such as the one described could be implemented in a search engine such as Solr (I have a little experience of the basics of this, but not performing complex sorting).
- Suggestions on how best to perform the sorting in PHP, if the other two options are not viable.

**EDIT:**

I've made some good progress on this, thanks (particularly @Neil).  I've opened a separate question up ( [Groupwise MAX() on a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841529/groupwise-max-on-a-subquery) ), which contains some of my progress so far.

Comment: Are you using an 'order by' clause already?

Comment: Right now there is no order by clause, as I'm not entirely sure what I could order by to achieve the specific ordering that is required.

Comment: 100.000 courses? I'd guess you have duplicate courses by the subject, say 300 History courses, 600 English courses etc? How many distinct subjects are there in total?

Comment: Yes, there will be duplicate courses. I'm currently adding a LIKE clause for each course entered to filter the results down, but that doesn't handle the ordering obviously. I don't know the exact number of distinct courses as I don't have the DB to hand right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find schools by the number of matching courses is simple:

```
SELECT schoolId, COUNT(*) AS schoolCount
  FROM Courses
  WHERE name IN ('History', 'French')
  GROUP BY schoolId
```

If this was all you needed, you could `ORDER BY schoolCount DESC` to get them in the order you want.

To find partnerships with matching courses, you first need to find the partnerships that have the course at at least one school:

```
SELECT partnershipId, COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS partnershipCount
  FROM SchoolPartnership
  INNER JOIN Courses ON Course.schoolId = SchoolPartnership.schoolId
  WHERE name IN ('History', 'French')
  GROUP BY partnershipId
```

Note that `DISTINCT` is needed because we don't care how many schools in the partnership have that course. If you don't have `DISTINCT` then you could use a subselect instead:

```
SELECT partnershipId, COUNT(*) AS partnershipCount
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT partnershipId, name
      FROM SchoolPartnership
      INNER JOIN Courses ON Course.schoolId = SchoolPartnership.schoolId
      WHERE name IN ('History', 'French'))
  GROUP BY partnershipId
```

You can then use the first and last query above as subselects in a join with SchoolPartnership to order the schools in descending order of partnershipMatches and schoolMatches. (Note that I assume that all schools are in a partnership of at least one school.) I think the final query will look like this:

```
SELECT SchoolMatches.schoolID
  FROM (
    SELECT schoolId, COUNT(*) AS schoolCount
      FROM Courses
      WHERE name IN ('History', 'French')
      GROUP BY schoolId
  ) SchoolMatches
  JOIN SchoolPartnership ON SchoolMatches.schoolID = SchoolPartnership.schoolID
  JOIN (
    SELECT partnershipId, COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS partnershipCount
      FROM SchoolPartnership
      INNER JOIN Courses ON Course.schoolId = SchoolPartnership.schoolId
      WHERE name IN ('History', 'French')
      GROUP BY partnershipId
   ) PartnershipMatches ON SchoolPartnership.schoolId = PartnershipMatches.schoolId
   ORDER BY PartnershipMatches.partnershipCount DESC, SchoolMatches.SchoolCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I think this looks pretty close to what I need.  My main concern is that if a school offered 2 French courses (I'd be using LIKE rather than =), e.g "Beginner's French" and "Advanced French", this would score equally with a school that provided French and History courses. Can you think of a way to incorporate the fact that each course must be present at a school or in a partnership?

Comment: Also, schools may not belong to a partnership at all (I should've mentioned that). I'm thinking I could probably alter some of the joins to become LEFT joins to deal with that fact.

Comment: Finally, I'm not 100% sure on this, as I've not tested it, but I don't think your solution would guarantee that the schools in the partnership appear together.  E.g. Schools P and Q both teach French, Schools R and S both teach History: P and R are partners, Q and S are partners.  In this case, P and R should appear next to each other in the results, as should Q and S.

Comment: @ChrisC Sorry for not replying earlier but I had to force-reload the page to get my browser to pick up on the site changes.

Comment: @ChrisC For schools not in a partnership I think you would have to left join `SchoolMatches` with the inner join of `SchoolPartnership` and `PartnershipMatches`.

Comment: @ChrisC When I wrote the query I thought that the school with the most number of matches would be preferred, i.e. if Q and R both teach French and R and S both teach History then R would be listed first. To get P listed next to R (when possibly it should not appear at all as it has no matching courses!) could be done by inserting an ordering on `partnershipId` but then R could get listed last...

Comment: @ChrisC The only way I can see how to deal with multiple courses with similar names will only result in schools or partnerships that provide all the necessary courses, not just some of them.

Comment: No problem. A quick update: I came to the same conclusion as you regarding ordering by partnershipId and have implemented that in my query.  I came up with a solution to deal with the fact that each course must be represented: By using something like the following: `SELECT ((CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN c.title LIKE '%French%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN cm.title LIKE '%History%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))`

Comment: For info, the second subquery dealing with the partnership ordering is visible here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841529/groupwise-max-on-a-subquery/14841629#comment20806986_14841629 . The rest of the query looks much as you provided it, but with the use of CASE/LIKE. I've not been able to resolve my groupwise MAX issue in SQL, so am currently identifying the "best partnership" post-query in PHP.

Comment: @ChrisC Maybe you could join to a subquery `SELECT DISTINCT schoolId FROM Courses WHERE name IN ('History', 'French')` (or `WHERE title LIKE '%History%' OR title LIKE '%French%'` or whatever).

Comment: I've not fixed all of my issues with the query, but I've got far enough with it that I've been able to fix the last few issues in the application itself.  I'm accepting this answer as it was a great starting point in building the final query.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem with site's pages. We created special denormilized search table with all params to perform search with no sub queries or joins. All data was duplicated, so when something changes we update all denormalizar data. We used background tasks for syncronizing data, so search results could be not actual for some small time.

May be it seems complicated, but it only way if your data and request will grow up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'd considered adding a denormalised table/view for this if the query turns out to be slow, but I still have the problem of ordering the data when I extract it from the denormalised table.  I have a feeling I am wasting my time trying to do the ordering in SQL.

Answer (score -2):

```
filter_var('sgamgee@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); // Returns "sgamgee@example.com"
```

This is a valid email address.

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable